# nested route component rendering twice

Tags: reactjs

I recently include nested routing in my project and i do have some problems with that.  If I render the component which is in the nested route that rendering in my page twice.

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

export default function App(){
      return(
        <BrowserRouter>
         <Routes>   
            <Route path = '/show/:id' element={<View/>} > 
              <Route path = 'home' element = {<ViewHome/>}> 
                <Route path='overview' element={<Overview/>} />
                <Route path='packages' element={<Packages/>} />
                <Route path='taskItems' element={<Tasks/>} />
                <Route path='features' element={<Features/>} />
                <Route path='github' element={<Git/>} />
              </Route>
              <Route path='progress' element= {<Progress />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      )
}

root.render(
    <App/>
);
```

this is where i have the links

```
function Lists(props){

    var overviewPath = `overview`
    var packagePath = `packages`
    var taskPath = `taskItems`
    var featurePath = `features`
    var gitPath = `github`
    var aboutPath = `about`

    return(
        
        <div className="viewList">
            <nav>
            <Link to={overviewPath}>Overview</Link><br/>
            <Link to={packagePath}>Packages</Link><br/>
            <Link to={taskPath}>Tasks</Link><br/>
            <Link to={featurePath}>Features</Link><br/>
            <Link to={gitPath}>GitHub</Link><br/>
            <Link to={aboutPath}>about</Link><br/>
            </nav>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Lists;
```

```
function Tasks(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Typography variant= 'h3' >Tasks</Typography>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Tasks;
```

and this my tasks component[image]

and this is I got in my page but i need to render that h1 once only.  Thank you advance

repository -> https://github.com/bharathkumarsaravanan/Todo-App
frontend -> components

Comment: Hey Bharath please add code where you call tasks

Comment: Could You add all of Your code or provide link to the repo?

Comment: @MarioG8 I added u can check now

Comment: Hey, i still didn't see where you added tasks?! please add code that contains the Tasks file/page/component.

Comment: @VarunKaklia Todo-App/frontend/src/components/View/viewRoutes/Tasks.jsx

Comment: @BharathKumar You fixed that issue ?